# Оптимальное хранение вопросов для теста на Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Подскажите как лучше всего хранить вопросы для теста на **Vue.js**.
Тест будет такого вида, как от определенно ответа появляться след вопрос исходят как ответили на предыдущий.

Для яркого понимание скажет тест психологического типа, как вы понимаете исходят из ответа появляются новые вопросы.

Идеи две у меня, тупо списком закинуть.. и скажем про нумеровать и вызывать по сопоставлению `ответ= новый вопрос`. Как то олдскульно это. Вторая идея положить все в **Json** древовидный и как то идти по дереву.

Если есть еще варианты выслушаю.

В дополнение к вопросу, оптимальная реализация тестирования. Как бы `if else` городить все это не годится наверное. Какие есть идеи на построение кода для тестирования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json - нормальный вариант, или просто js файл с объектом, описывающим тест. Каждый вопрос можно представить в виде объекта с необходимыми атрибутами, включая ответы. В ответы, при необходимости, добавить id следующего вопроса для реализации логики переходов.